# Haar Functionals and Coquasi-triangular Structures

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, noncommutative-geometry, haar-measure

In this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67537/compact-quantum-groups-from-hopf-algebras) it is mentioned that the coordinate algebra $C_q[G]$ Drinfeld--Jimbo algebras, for $G$ a compact semi-simple Lie group, admit a unique positive definite Haar functional. I was wondering if this can be shown to have anything to do with their coquasi-triangular structure?